# como puedo sacar un valor que esta dentro de dos diccionario

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular

tengo el valor `objeto={canal_venta}`
pero si imprimo `canal_veta` me arroja esto `{u'TEXT': u'RED', u'VALUE': u'RED'}`
es decir como puedo acceder al valor de canal venta

Estaba intentando de esta forma, pero es incorrecta

```
print objeto["canal_venta"["VALUE"]]
```

Comment: Digo yo que será `print objeto["canal_venta"]["VALUE"]`

Comment: cierto, muchas gracias, soy un poco tonto aun en python